# Downloading images with restrictions using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download an image from a website, but when I save the image from the `src` tag I get a generic image.

The html tag looks like this:

```
<img alt="" data-width="2448" data-height="2448" data-frame="1" data-src="//photo.yupoo.com/huazeltd/4a4591ca/big.jpg" data-origin-src="//photo.yupoo.com/huazeltd/4a4591ca/4a0a44c6.jpg" data-type="photo" data-album-id="62862043" data-videoformats="" data-path="/huazeltd/4a4591ca/4a0a44c6.jpg" class="autocover image__img image__portrait" src="//photo.yupoo.com/huazeltd/4a4591ca/small.jpg">
```

The part of my code that it relevent to this task is as follows:

```
with requests.Session() as c:
    c.get('https://huazeltd.x.yupoo.com/albums/62862043?uid=1&referrercate=237897')
    res = c.get(f'https://photo.yupoo.com/huazeltd/4a4591ca/small.jpg')
    if res.status_code == 200:
        with open(f"img/{p.split('/')[-1]}", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(res.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things:

1) you aren't assigning the result of c.get to res, so that's empty

2) there is no `https://` before the second request

I haven't tried the code as is, but when modified as follows:

```
import requests
def get_photos(url):
    with requests.Session() as c:
        c.get(url)
        c.headers.update({'referer': url})
        res = c.get('https://photo.yupoo.com/huazeltd/4a4591ca/small.jpg')
        if res.status_code == 200:
            return res.content
```

it (now) returns the correct content, as tested with:

```
url = 'https://huazeltd.x.yupoo.com/albums/62862043?uid=1&referrercate=237897'
with open('photo.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(get_photos(url))
```

Please note I am explicitly setting the referrer now.

Comment: sorry I missed them when I copied and pasted the code. Still this answer does not get the correct image. instead it download a generic image.